# Файл php доступен с расширением xml

Tags: xml, php

Всем привет.

Есть файл php в котором выполняется простенький скрипт и выдает содержимое в виде xml. 
Установил заголовки с помощью функции header

```
header('Content-Type: application/xml; charset=cp1251');
header("Pragma: no-cache");
```

Проблема в том что этот файл доступен по адресу вида site.ru/xml.php
Как можно сделать чтобы при обращении по адресу site.ru/xml.xml выдавало содержимое xml.php?

Comment: Используйте mod_rewrite в .htaccess. Примеров масса.

Comment: @void не нашел ни одного рабочего

Answer (score 1):

Настроить исполняемые файлы для Apache. по дефолту ето php и phtml. Просто дописать туда xml. Тогда ети файлы будут исполняться как .php

Можно написать в *.htaccess*

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .xml
```

Comment: сделал, но не работает

Comment: Пробуй RewriteRule ^somefile.xml$ somephpfile.php [NC]

Comment: @myvzar тоже не работает, хотел уточнить что я пробую в подкаталоге, в корне есть свой файл .htaccess но он ведь по идее не должен влиять.